# UIImagePickerController TakePicture Method Not Saving To Camera Roll

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

Thank you for reading,
I am making a camera timer app, and when the timer hits 0 a picture is meant to be taken. However, it isn't. :c.

HERE is the code for showing the PickerController and the Overlay for my new controls. (ViewDidLoad method is too early to load this.)

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    overlayView.hidden = false;
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController  alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
[imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayView;
```

}

HERE is the code for when the timer hits 0 and a picture is meant to be  taken.

```
//cameraTimeInt is the timer//
if(cameraTimeInt ==0){

//timerDisplay is the picture displaying the countdown to 0//
        [timerDisplay setImage:NULL];

        [imagePicker takePicture];



    }
```

HERE is the code when you click the 'takepicture' button.

```
-(IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender {




    cameraTimeInt = timeSlider.value;



    NSTimer *timerStart = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerTickStart:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timerStart forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];



}
```

I know the code is a bit sloppy, but if anyone has any ideas, it would be GREATLY appreciated :)

ALSO the error I am getting is this:

CameraTimer[392:907] UIImagePickerController: ignoring request to take picture; image is already being captured or camera not yet ready.

It appears to be trying to take two images, as I hear the clicking (camera take picture noise) twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editted

```
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_imgView.image, nil, nil, nil);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your case, time of `NSTimer` is very early to take photo. so, change it to **7 second**
because it take photo may be  when all component in initialize process.

```
-(IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender {

    cameraTimeInt = timeSlider.value;

    NSTimer *timerStart = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:7 target:self selector:@selector(timerTickStart:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timerStart forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

}
```